# FOSUserBundle make relationship with my own table

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata

Im using the FOSUserBundle in symfony2, it's works very well but I have to create for example another table like Entry, with fields:

```
 user_id, description,...
```

I need to make a relationship between the `user` table and `Entry` table. What is the best way to make the relationship One to Many? Which class I should extend?

I get this error:

`Entry has no association named ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User`

My code is:

```
   /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User",  inversedBy="entry")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/

protected $users;
```

I use this instruccion:

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT b
                               FROM LoggerFrontendBundle:Entry a JOIN a.ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User b
                       ') ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

User Entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="path to new Entity", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $name;
```

New Entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="path to User Entity", inversedBy="name")
*/
protected $user;
```

From the controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
// when you query users, you get the information from the new Entity.
$users = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User')->findAll();

return array('users' => $user); // return the array of user information
```

Twig:

```
{% for user in users %} // loop through users<br/>

{{ user.name.getName }} // you can call user.getname or user.getEmail , you can add the name from the Entity on and get the fields from the new Entity like user.name.getName etc...

{% endfor %} //end loop
```

Comment: ok, but i have refresh my question because i try it but when i doesn't work