# How to map user_id field to other tables Symfony FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.2

How do I map user_id field from user table to other tables. I am using Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle.

I have already tried by this way

My Contacts Entity

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $user;
```

My User Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contacts", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $contact;
```

I did

```
doctrine:schema:update --force 

Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

There should be user_id field added to contacts table.

I tried adding cascade -- [Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305055/fosuserbundle-make-relationship-with-my-own-table)

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contacts", mappedBy="user",cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $contact;
```

But even that is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your contact entity

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $user;
```

It should be

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $user;
```

Missing extra star in doc block

FYI: [DOC Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#DocBlock)

Comment: Thanks. This is most annoying thing about doctrine